# C++ namespaced function template specialization alternative using overloading with class pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, overloading

So I've come across a problem where using function template specialization forces me to write the function in the same namespace as the function template. I cannot do this because some other code requires to define some function template within another specific namespace.

To work-around the namespace issue, I'm trying to use function overloading instead. Furthermore, these functions return value need to be `constexpr`, so I could not overload using a class reference, so I used a class pointer instead.

So I ended up with this:

```
template<class T> constexpr auto getName(T* const) { return ""; }
```

and then I overload them like this:

```
inline constexpr auto getName(int* const) { return "int"; }
```

This works fine and allows me to call the correct overload using a `nullptr` trick like this:

```
auto name = getName((int* const)nullptr);
```

My problem is it seems I am unable to overload this when the type is an array. I would like to be able to overload when the type is `int[]`, and return the string `"int[]"` in that case.

Perhaps there is a better solution to avoid the namespace hell for function template specialization? I know this all stinks but I could not find a better alternative yet.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you could use `typeid` for this specific case.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I forgot to mention that I cannot use rtti in my case.

Comment: `int(&)[size]`, with  template size. do you need it?

Comment: @acade unfortunately I can't use class reference in my case. Your solution works fine if I could use references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use "tag" instead:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag{};

// template <typename T>
//constexpr auto getName(Tag<T>) { return ""; }

inline constexpr auto getName(Tag<int>) { return "int"; }

inline constexpr auto getName(Tag<int[]>) { return "int[]"; }

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto registerName(Tag<int[N]>) { return "int[N]"; }
```

[Demo](http://cpp.sh/5kzyd)

Comment: I do not see how this tag can be used in the real life, without calling code actually knowing it deals with the array - at which point it  can simply call a different function instead.

Comment: @SergeyA: `constexpr auto name = getName((int* const)nullptr);` would be `constexpr auto name = getName(Tag<int>{});` (where I suppose `int` would be `T` in generic code). but indeed `getName<T>()` would also work but handling `getName<std::vector<T>>()` would be more problematic.

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried your solution but it didn't work for the array type, online test: http://cpp.sh/9mxh7

Comment: @Jarod42 oh nice I didn't think to combine it with the template size constant. It works now, cheers!